# Adding elements to a hashmap with numeric keys

Tags: r, hashmap

I am using a hashmap to keep track of a series of data paris over time, and I would like to know how you can keep appending them to the main hashmap.

Here is an example:

```
library(hash)

a = 2
h = hash(a, "V")
ls(h)
h[["2"]]
```

Here a gets coerced into using its numerical value as a character. As expected the result is the pair: 2-V. 
Here is where I don't understand how this works. I want to add more key value pairs to the hashmap (I don't know the all at the beginning so I cant make a general list, and then make a hash out of it.

For example:

```
b = 67
h$b = "x" 
h[[b]] = "x"
```

The first method gives me the pair b-x rather than 67-x, and the second method doesnt actually work...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting the number to a character type using `as.character()`:

```
b <- 67
h <- hash(b, "V")
h[[as.character(b)]]
[1] "V"
```

This will also work:

```
h$"67"
```

But the `hash` library does not appear to support referencing the hash this way using a numeric variable.

Comment: I had tried that and gotten nowhere...tried again and it works.lol must have been bad syntax on my end :) TNX!